# Use python to get lastest 2 commits from Github repo

Tags: python, git, github, pygithub

I am am attempting to get all commits for a specific branch of a repo using the following code. My end goal is to only get the top 2 commits.

The issue I am running into is that the commits being returned are only for a specific user. I want to get the latest commits regardless of user, but have been unable to get it to work.

```
from pygithub3 import Github

github_client = Github(account=account, user=user, token=auth_token, repo=repo_name)

repo_commits = github_client.repos.commits.list(sha='dev')
```

Comment: Just a guess, did you try removing 'user' from the client constructor?

Comment: Yes, I did. No commits were returned.